# Fill a column to the bottom of content

Tags: html

Been trying to figure this out all day!

On load, if the viewport is too short to display all the content, the wrapper div doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the content. If I scroll down, the wrapper div stays the height of the original viewport.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3wueg95e/

I found this solution: http://www.geekicon.net/thinktank/index.shtml/article/643
However, if i change the wrapper position to absolute, the whole wrapper moves to the right.

I'm also wondering why if i set eight to default, the wrapper disappears.

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
  <div class="linkbar" id="logo"><img src="images/gologo.png" width="150" height="100" alt="nothing to see here"/></div> 
  <div class="linkbar" id="link1"><img src="images/burrito.png" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="linkbar" id="link2"><img src="images/dickshamburger.png" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="linkbar" id="link3"><img src="images/potstickers.png"  alt=""/></div>
  <div class="linkbar" id="link4"><img src="images/chickenwaffles.png" alt=""/></div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="sidebarlinks">
        <li><h2>GRUBBIN ON:</h2></li>
        <li>burritos</li>
        <li>sandwiches</li>
        <li>chili</li>
        <li>bbq</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h1>Blog Post Title</h1>
    <div class="blogpic"><img src="images/giordano.jpeg" alt=""/><img src="images/giordano.jpeg" width="259" height="194" alt=""/></div>

    <div class ="blogtext">   
        <p class="where">Where: Giordano Bros. - 16th and Valencia, SF</p>
        <p class="whatfood">What: Hot Capicola and Fried Pickles</p>
        <ol>
            <li>fact number one about this bomb food</li>
            <li>fact number two about this bomb food</li>
            <li>fact number three about this bomb food</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="footer">Super cool content with copyrights and links</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html  {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #A8E26F;
    font-family: droid-sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #151515;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 750px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(url);
    background-color: #FDF9FF;
    font-family: droid sans;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.linkbar {
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: 50%;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: 150px 0100px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#header img {
    display: inline;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
#logo {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 90px;
}
#link1 {
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#link2 {
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#link3 {
    letter-spacing: 7px;
}

#wrapper #sidebar p {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: droid-sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    font-family: droid-sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;

}
.main {
    width: 600px;
    font-family: droid-sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.linkbar img {
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    width: 135px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 90px;
}

#sidebarlinks {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
h1, h2 {
    margin-top: 8px;
    bottom: 0pt;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 19px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: #FF4246;
    font-family: droid-sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    left: 0px;
}
.main p {
    padding-left: 14px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.blogpic {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.blogpic img {
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.blogtext {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
.blogtext ol {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    clear: left;
    font-size: small;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `html, body, #wrapper` all to height: 100%, they will always be as high as the viewport. So if your content is larger than that you need something like

```
#wrapper { overflow: auto; }
```

This will add scrollbars if necessary to your `#wrapper`.